# wsl can't find file that's there

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I thought I would use wsl (windows subsystem for Linux) to cross-compile an application I have. I downloaded a .tar of the cross system, moved the .tar to wsl, untarred it, and now I can't run the compiler. I don't understand! And I am obviously brand new at wsl :)

Here's what I see:

```
rw@seven:~$ ln -s /opt/crosstool/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ ct
rw@seven:~$ ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++
-bash: ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++: No such file or directory
rw@seven:~$ ll ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++
-rwxr-xr-x 2 500 500 206621 Feb 12  2006 ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++*
rw@seven:~$ file ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++
ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, with debug_info, not stripped
rw@seven:~$ strace ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++
execve("ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++", ["ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++"], 0x7ffe4559ecf0 /* 21 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
strace: exec: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 1 +++
rw@seven:~$ ldd ct/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++
        not a dynamic executable
rw@seven:~$
```

Is there some way to run this compiler under wsl?

It's wsl 2. Ubuntu. Windows 10.

```
rw@seven:~$ uname -a
Linux seven 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does the interpreter file `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` exist? You may need to install some 32-bit shared libraries.

Comment: This may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Mark.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit
solved my immediate problem. Which leads me to the next problem, of course :)